# How can I deploy a multi-file ClickOnce custom prerequisite?

Tags: clickonce, prerequisites

I have created a ClickOnce application in which I need a prerequisite to be installed, which I have also created.  The prerequisite needs to download two2 files-- an executable and an additional file.  When I run the prerequisite installation, the additional file could not be found and hence fails.  Here are the steps I've followed trying to diagnose of fix this problem.

1. I've looked in the tmp folder and only the executable is present.
2. The products.xml holds two entries for both files in the  attribute.
3. The additional file is deployed correctly to the web server.
4. The additional file is an .xpi file for which a MIME type was added to IIS.
5. I tried to set `CopyAllPackageFiles = "true"` but that hasn't helped.

Please advice.